# BottomSheetBehavior leaking fragment?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I'm analyzing my app using LeakCanary 2.5.

I've a hard time to figure out one of the last memory leaks I found during testing. I don't really get what I'm doing wrong here.

The LeakCanary log looks like this:

Image:

[image: LeakCanary Java Memory Dump Image]

Log:

```
┬───
│ GC Root: Global variable in native code
│
├─ myApp.view.MyView instance
│    Leaking: NO (MainActivity↓ is not leaking and View attached)
│    View is part of a window view hierarchy
│    View.mAttachInfo is not null (view attached)
│    View.mID = R.id.my_view
│    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
│    mContext instance of myApp.activity.MainActivity with mDestroyed
│    = false
│    ↓ MyView.mContext
├─ myApp.activity.MainActivity instance
│    Leaking: NO (ConstraintLayout↓ is not leaking and Activity#mDestroyed is
│    false)
│    mApplication instance of androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication
│    mBase instance of androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper, not
│    wrapping known Android context
│    ↓ MainActivity._bottomSheet
├─ androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout instance
│    Leaking: NO (View attached)
│    View is part of a window view hierarchy
│    View.mAttachInfo is not null (view attached)
│    View.mID = R.id.bottom_sheet
│    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
│    mContext instance of myApp.activity.MainActivity with mDestroyed
│    = false
│    ↓ ConstraintLayout.mKeyedTags
│                       ~~~~~~~~~~
├─ android.util.SparseArray instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 2427 bytes in 83 objects
│    ↓ SparseArray.mValues
│                  ~~~~~~~
├─ java.lang.Object[] array
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 2394 bytes in 81 objects
│    ↓ Object[].[1]
│               ~~~
╰→ myApp.fragment.MetadataFragment instance
     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because myApp.
     fragment.MetadataFragment received Fragment#onDestroy() callback and
     Fragment#mFragmentManager is null)
     Retaining 2258 bytes in 75 objects
     key = 0409b825-f199-4049-95b1-8e572c92a078
     watchDurationMillis = 6335
     retainedDurationMillis = 1335
```

The bottom sheet XML definition looks like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="100dp"
  android:background="?attr/bottom_sheet_background"
  app:behavior_hideable="false"
  app:behavior_peekHeight="55dp"
  app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">
```

As the log shows I store a reference of `_bottomSheet` in my MainActivity. I programmatically get the BottomSheetBehaviour like that `BottomSheetBehavior.from(_bottomSheet);` to attach a `addBottomSheetCallback`.

In my activity's `onDestroy` I think I clean up but obviously something is missing:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
  super.onDestroy();
  ...

  _bottomSheetBehavior.removeBottomSheetCallback(_bottomSheetBehaviorCallBack);
  _bottomSheet = null;

  ...
}
```

What I think I read in the LeakCanary log is that the `ConstraintLayout` holding a Tag to the `MetadataFragment`. I found the variable LeakCanary is referring about `mKeyedTags` in the `View` class of Android (`ConstraintLayout extends ViewGroup` -> `ViewGroup extends View`).

I've checked my code and my XML and I don't use Tags. What do I miss here?

[image: Android View class]

Comment: That's a tricky one. Not sure what put the fragment as a tag of that layout. One thing that would help: figure out the value of "key" using the heap dump. It's going to be an int, then we have to find if it corresponds to R.id.something. I could help if I had access to the heap dump.

Comment: To what I remember I checked `key` in debug mode to see what int it is. I haven't checked with any R.id.something though but I saw that the this key is changing once I do a configuration change (rotate the phone).